# Is it possible to delete the first few row of xlsx files (over 100 files) with multiple sheets in r?

Tags: r, excel, tidyverse, apache-arrow

I have a series of xlsx files (> 200mb each) with multiple sheets. Only the first sheet of the files contain an introduction, something likes:

| This table is designed for balabala etc... | balabala |
| --- | --- |
| Reference Key | date |
| 1 | 01/01/1999 |

The number of lines of introductions from each files are not the same, but all the datasets start with `Reference Key` variable.

Is it possible to avoid reading the whole datasets and deleting the introductions, then merging the sheets from same file into one xlsx file?

Comment: But skip option in `readxl::read_excel ` also skips n rows in every sheet, which is not what I want

Comment: Also, the speed of readxl::read_excel is still too slow for me, especially comparing with fread...

Comment: `fread` does not support reading `xlsx` format.

Comment: `read_excel(path, sheet, skip=ifelse(sheet == 1, 1, 0), ...)`

Comment: It would be extremely slow even if you can do it. There is a good chance that your machine will  crash if it does not have enough ram.

Comment: That's right, so I am trying to find a way that I can use `arrow::read_dataset` to read xlsx directly. But it seems only support csv, and feather etc...

Comment: I asked a programmer and he advised me to use VBA to solve the problem. Deleting the introduction by myself....I think it is very stupid but have no choice.

Comment: You said the files are xlsx, but afaict `arrow::open_dataset` only supports `c("parquet", "arrow", "ipc", "feather", "csv", "tsv", "text")`. I understand your hope to use the "lazy" mechanism of arrow for this, but you have no current path through `arrow` unless you convert each of your xlsx files to one of those first.

Comment: You are right. So the question will be converted into 'how to convert xlsx files with multiple sheets into csv with skip function (only apply to first sheet) efficiently?'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick process for converting a set of `xlsx` files with one or more sheets each into a directory tree of CSV files. The loop finds a line that starts with `"Reference Key"` and, if found, skips to that row; if not found, it skips nothing, assuming that `readxl::read_excel` will guess appropriately.

```r
files <- list.files(pattern = "xlsx$", full.names = TRUE)
for (fn in files) {
  dirnm <- tools::file_path_sans_ext(fn)
  dir.create(dirnm, showWarnings = FALSE)
  for (sht in readxl::excel_sheets(fn)) {
    dat <- readxl::read_excel(fn, sht, n_max = 4, col_types = "text")
    skip <- grep("Reference Key", dat[[1]])[1]
    if (is.na(skip)) skip <- 0L
    newname <- file.path(dirnm, paste0(sht, ".csv"))
    readxl::read_excel(fn, sht, skip = skip) |>
      write.csv(newname, row.names = FALSE)
  }
}
```

This works for me given two files:

- `Book1.xlsx` with sheets `Sheet1` and `Sheet2`;
- `Book2.xlsx` with sheets `Sheet1` and `Sheet2`.

After this, we now have subdirs with CSV files:

```r
files
# [1] "./Book1.xlsx" "./Book2.xlsx"
list.files(pattern = "csv$", recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)
# [1] "./Book1/Sheet1.csv" "./Book1/Sheet2.csv" "./Book2/Sheet1.csv" "./Book2/Sheet2.csv"
```

This should work well for whatever your purpose. If you're dealing with large amounts of data, there are many reasons why you many prefer to write directly to parquet format instead of CSV:

- **lazy reading**: in a dplyr pipe, you can use a somewhat-reduced set of `mutate`, `filter`, `select`, and such, and none of the data is read into memory until you finally `%>% collect()` the data, similar to `dbplyr` and `dtplyr`;
- **combine files**: if the schema (columns/types) are all the same, then you can use `arrow::open_dataset` once with *all* (or a subset of) files, and it will virtually combine them, optionally using hive-partitioning (not used here necessarily, but can be added if applicable);
- **native types**: the classes (and attributes) of the R `data.frame` produced by `read_excel` are preserved in the parquet file, so if your excel data includes dates, timestamps, etc, you can set this before saving to parquets, and when you read the parquets they will be the correct classes again.

For that, I think I would modify the inner-most portion of the loop to be something like:

```r
    newname <- file.path(dirnm, paste0(sht, ".pq"))
    readxl::read_excel(fn, sht, skip = skip) %>%
      mutate(
        thedata = as.Date(somedate, format = "....."),
        thetime = as.POSIXct(somestamp, format = ".....")
      ) %>%
      arrow::write_parquet(newname)
```

and then use `arrow::open_dataset` on each file (if desired) or something like this if the schema are all the same:

```r
ds <- list.files(basename(files), pattern = "pq$", recursive = TRUE) |>
  arrow::open_dataset()
```

and have *lazy* access to all of the data in one object.

Comment: One of the reason I used csv is that, I can use a VBA program to convert xlsx to csv easily. If R can convert xlsx into other formats efficiently, then there is no need to use csv...

Answer (score 2):

To expand on my comment above.  Untested code, since you haven't given us a reproducible example.

```
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)

# Make the obvious edit here
myFiles <- list.files(path="<your path>", pattern="xlsx")

# Read one file
readFile <- function(f) {
  sheets <- excel_sheets(f)
  lapply(
    seq_along(sheets),
    function(x) read_excel(f, sheet=x, skip=ifelse(x == 1, 1, 0))
  ) %>% 
  # Combine all sheets in the file into a single data frame
  bind_rows()
}

# Process your files
excelFiles <- lapply(myFiles, readFile)
```